# iOS company name for distributing apps to App Store

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I've had a look around SO and Google but can't find a definite and specific answer, maybe it's supposed to be obvious!

But, I haven't submitted an app to the store before so when I went to add one through iTunes Connect, the first thing it says is

```
Specify the company or developer name to display on the App Store for your apps.
The company name cannot be changed, so be sure to enter the correct name.
```

Now, does setting that company name apply to ALL apps I upload after setting it or does it ask you this question and let you set it every time you add a new app?

If it sets it for all apps, does it have to match the company name I've used to register my iOS developer account with? When I created the account I gave the name Company Ltd, so would I strictly have to use Company Ltd when setting the company name to be displayed on the App Store?

Many thanks.

Comment: I think company name is fixed for the app you are going to submit (can change for subsequent different apps).

Comment: It should match your own legal company name and it can never be changed for any other apps submitted under the same developer account.  Changing it at all for the entire account requires a lot of paperwork and delay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally the company name will (and can) not change after it is set (well they can do it but they request a load of legal papers and stuff).

However, if you indeed run a company that should not matter and you should already know what you are doing. You have to be careful though, as if you pretend to be a company and you are not (e.g. as individual developer), you might run into legal issues which can cause some trouble to say the least (even if you "only" plan to release free apps).

Comment: Thanks for this info. We created an App but wanted to release it under a different company name that we own, but if that affects all our future apps then we'll just use our own :)

Comment: Well if your app needs a different brand, I'm sure you could simply create a different account (assuming that you have all the legal stuff clear and have proof for Apple that everything is allright).

Answer (score 1):

In iTunes Connect, when you add a new application, they specify :

> "[...] name to display on the App Store for your app**s** [...]"

apps is plural, so it means it's for all this account's apps.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do it online, you have to request apple to do is, by calling them.

To request a migration of your individual developer membership to a company developer membership, first make sure that you meet our initial migration requirements:

1. You have an active individual developer program membership.
2. Your company does not operate as a sole proprietorship, DBA, fictitious name, trade name, or branch.
3. You are a founder or cofounder of your company.
4. You have authority to bind your company to Apple Developer Program agreements.
5. Your company does not already hold an active or expired company membership.
6. If you have paid apps, you have agreed to the latest Paid Apps contract in the Contracts, Tax, and Banking module of iTunes Connect.
7. You are able to obtain a DUNS number for your company: https://developer.apple.com/support/D-U-N-S.

If you do not meet our migration requirements, you may use a separate Apple ID to enroll your company in an Apple Developer Program.

To proceed with your migration request, contact apple by phone (https://developer.apple.com/contact/phone) or send them an email with the following information:

- Confirm that you meet the initial migration requirements listed above.
- Provide the name of the company to which you would like to migrate your individual membership.

After your information has been reviewed and accepted, they will send you an email with instructions for completing the migration. During this process, you will be unable to access the Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles portal.

If you need to update your individual bank information, do so before you start the company migration.

Hope this helps.